# Configure TexnicCenter with something else than Adobe Reader X

Tags: installing, viewers, texniccenter

My Adobe decided it should be version X now, and it misbehaves in so many ways. One way is that it is impossible to get it to open a pdf document from within TexnicCenter (or I missed something...) Pressing F5 opens up the Adobe with some start menu asking me to open a recent file blablabla. But not the file I want to see. And TexnicCenter tells me the command could not be executed.

I've had it with Adobe bloatware, so I want to shift to something else. Nitro comes to mind, as I find it a decent PDF reader and editor. So I wondered if anybody had experience setting up TexnicCenter with [Nitro](http://www.nitroreader.com/tour/Default.aspx), as I couldn't really find anything on the net. Or is there another one that is better ([Sumatra](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) is mentioned as it gives pdfsync, but again, I have no experience in this)

Thank you for your answers.

EDIT :

After some more searching around, I found that there is apparently a problem with the server name for Adobe ( see [this discussion](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3323076) ). Still, I've had it with those *censored. more censored*. So any help on linking TC with either Nitro or something else is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: This] This would be my TXC output profile for working with [Sumatra](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html). It allows forward and backward search and you can keep the pdf-file open while compiling. The commands are: (Check if your paths are right)

1:

```
C:\Programme\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -inverse-search "\"C:\Programme\TeXnicCenter\TEXCNTR.EXE\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]'\""
```

2:

```
[Open("%bm.pdf",0,1,1)]
```

3:

```
[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,0)]
```

4:

```
[DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][DocClose("%bm.pdf")]
```

You can also find tutorials for using TXC with Sumatra at [TeXnicCenter Tutorials](http://www.texniccenter.org/resources/tutorials).

Comment: Thx for the answer. Tried it out and it works like a charm.

Comment: A not-related tip: If you want to take a screenshot just of the current (not maximized) window, you can press `Alt`+`Print/Druck`. Spares you the cropping work and looks nicer :)

Comment: @doncherry: Thanks, I was always to lazy to search for this combination :)

Comment: For me this is working well, thank you, but ONE thing still annoys me: The viewer sumatra doesn't popup to the front (foreground), so I always have to select it. And about the inverse search: Is that normal that by double clicking the cursor does **NOT** automatically skip to the double-clicked word but **only** to the paragraph/sentence/item??

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using sumatra pdf instead

It is recommended to use the -reuse-instance in the calling line to be configured inside texniccenter.

You may also want to take a look at the latest texmaker, as it comes with its on PDF viewer.

Comment: thx for the tip on the -reuse instance. For now I keep with TC, as I have all my projects at work in here, and the TC project files are not portable afaik.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your question but for anybody who wants to continue using Adobe solutions are discussed at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250472/texniccenter-adobe-reader-dc)

However, most PDF readers (including Adobe) can be used by changing from DDE Command to Command Line argument and using `“%bm.pdf”` with a leading space in the box. That’s for View project’s output and for Forward Search.

For many readers you have to use *Do not close* in the last option which means you have to close the pdf manually before recompiling. However, for viewers such as [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.pdf-software.co.uk/free-pdf-viewer-free-pdf-reader/) you can put `/close “%bm.pdf”` in the bottom box and the document will automatically close.

Comment: tried it, but with Adobe X that still doesn't really make it going smoothly...

Answer (score 2):

I want to mention that by installing SumatraPDF first and then TeXnicCenter, the steps form the tutorial are automized.

It takes you something like 5 minutes to get a fresh installation of MiKTeX, SumatraPDF and TeXnicCenter, while getting inverse-search etc.

1. Install latest MiKTeX  (I suggest picking "Install packages on the fly: YES")
2. Install latest SumatraPDF
3. Install latest TeXnicCenter (Don't forget to pick your language if something else than English)

Don't forget to choose "LaTeX=>PDF".

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the answers from Martyn and Adam Nellis solved this problem. Thanks a lot, folks. I am just putting it step by step, so someone else can use it.

1. **Adobe Reader X:** In Adobe Reader X, go to `Edit`->`Preferences`->`General` and uncheck `Enable Protected Mode at startup`.
2. **TeXnicCenter:** `Go to Build`->`Define Output Profiles`-> choose `Latex to PDF` -> `Viewer` tab

   For `View Project's Output` & `Forward Search`:

   - Command: `[DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][FileOpen("%bm.pdf")]`
   - Server: `AcroViewR10`
   - Topic: `control`

   For `Close document`:

   - Command: `[DocClose("%bm.pdf")]`
   - Server: `AcroViewR10`
   - Topic: `control`

If you are using MiKTeX version 2.9 you have to use `%tm` instead of `%bm`.