# LaTeX viewer and forward search: how to achieve?

Tags: texniccenter, forward-inverse-search

(solved)
I am facing some problem with viewing the PDF. I am using TeXnicCenter on windows.

How can I direct Adobe Reader 10.1 so that it opens at the place where the file was last edited?

This is my setup: (but this does not do what I want...)

I tried with Sumatra, it says command cannot be execute... Foxit does not close before opening....

Path

```
\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe
```

View output:

```
[DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][FileOpen("%bm.pdf")]
AcroViewR10  control
```

Forward Search

```
[DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][FileOpen("%bm.pdf")]
AcroViewR10  control
```

Close:

```
[DocClose("%bm.pdf")]
AcroViewR10  control
```

I want to achieve:

1. The viewer should close before opening... (so that I do not have to close before compile)
2. Should open at the place where I am currently editing...

If you are willing to reply, please kindly try to reply only if you know it works/worked for you.

Comment: Search technology does not work with Adobe Reader, and it's never likely to (the market for TeX users is too small for Adobe to worry about). You are better asking focussed questions on getting Sumatra to work, or choosing an editor with a build-in PDF view, such as TeXworks.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36411/586 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12500/configure-texniccenter-with-something-else-than-adobe-reader-x

Comment: @Torbjørn T, Thanks.

I have tried the example with Sumatra, It says can not execute command [ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,0)] ...

Comment: Just now I added, [Open("%bm.pdf",0,1,1)][ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)]  Now..there is no error, and forward search does *not* work. No luck.

Comment: Old bug report for Sumtra about this: http://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/issues/detail?id=515  Do you have the latest version of Sumatra?

Comment: I am using the configuration TeXnicCenter 2 Alpha - SumatraPDF and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Just updated Sumatra and configured again.. worked.

Thank you all!

Comment: @JosephWright: Turn your comment into an answer since @ Droid-Bird switched PDF viewers.

Comment: @JosephWright,

This is something about answer... I was looking for the approve sign after I clicked edit. There I could not find anything that i can use to say Answered. Here is the snap,
http://i42.tinypic.com/1174it4.jpg

Just an idea, is it possible just add a button on the question?

Comment: @Droid-Bird You don't edit to 'tick' an answer, but should see a pick mark by the side of the voting number/up/down graphic to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search technology does not work with Adobe Reader, and it's never likely to (the market for TeX users is too small for Adobe to worry about). You are better asking focussed questions on getting Sumatra to work, or choosing an editor with a build-in PDF view, such as TeXworks.

Also, the error given by Sumatra appeared in earlier versions, updating Sumatra may help.

Comment: Turned comment into 'answer' as requested.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a sentence, feel free to change/remove it.