# How to get TeXnicCenter to remember the last page viewed in output PDF (as done automatically by TeXworks)

Tags: texworks, texniccenter, viewers

I am using `LaTeX=>PDF`.

When using TeXworks if I change the source `.tex` file the PDF viewer remembers the last page which was viewed and shows that page in the output PDF.

Whilst using TeXnicCenter however, Adobe PDF reader resets to the first page.

How do I resolve this, can I change from using Adobe PDF? or can Adobe PDF be customised somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LaTeX viewer and forward search: how to achieve?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38922/latex-viewer-and-forward-search-how-to-achieve)

Comment: that relates to the place of last edit, I am looking for the place of last close (as done by Texworks)

Comment: If you open a file in TC and press F5 it triggers a forward search command which first opens the file and jumps to that location. (but it should be tested on TC 1 since I am using TC 2 Alpha version)

Comment: But I am changing the source and rebuilding CTRL+SHIFT+F5

Comment: have you looked at Sumatra pdf viewer? no need to close and re-open

Comment: The "close and re-open" feature is available with Adobe PDF reader. However it closes and re-opens to the beginning of the document (as opposed to the place the document was last closed).

Comment: I looked at Sumatra PDF it works fine, I added a more detailed response as a new reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @akk's answer:

add an `-reuse-instance` in the viewer tab where the complete path to `SumatraPDF` is defined. Then your reverse search should run.

Answer (score 6):

I have started to use Sumatra PDF. This works fine (although sometimes it appears to re-open at a page directly before the page which has changed). I have tested it for both Latex => PDF and Latex => PS => PDF

**Source:** Alexander Watson on Sep 08, 2011

**URL:** [SyncTeX with TeXnicCenter and SumatraPDF (Windows)](http://wiki.bath.ac.uk/display/latextricks/SyncTeX+with+TeXnicCenter+and+SumatraPDF+%28Windows%29)

**Text is below (for reference):**

To set up SyncTeX and synchronise your LaTeX source and PDF output, you need a PDF reader capable of forward and backward search. As far as I know, SumatraPDF is the only such program available for Windows, so here is a guide to getting it set up with TeXnicCenter.

1. Install SumatraPDF. You'll need to download and run the installer, but if you install it to somewhere on your H drive, you don't need administrator privileges. (Maybe this is bad practice, I don't know, but it works.)
2. Set up pdfLaTeX to generate SyncTeX information: In TeXnicCenter, go to Build/Define Output Profiles. Choose Latex => PDF, and add the following to Command line arguments...: `-synctex=-1`
3. Set up forward search: In the same TeXnicCenter dialogue, choose the Viewer tab.

   a. For 'Path to executable', find the file SumatraPDF.exe wherever you chose to install it.

   b. For 'View project's output', select DDE command, and enter `[Open("%bm.pdf",0,1,1)]`, `SUMATRA` and `control` in the boxes for `Command`, `Server` and `Topic` respectively.

   c. For `Forward Search`, select DDE command, and enter `[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,0)]`, `SUMATRA` and `control` in the corresponding boxes.
4. Set up backward search: In SumatraPDF, go to Settings/Options, and in the inverse search command line section, enter `"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TEXCNTR.exe" /ddecmd "[goto('%f', '%l')]"`, with all the quotes. (You might have to change the path to TeXnicCenter if you have it installed in a funny place.)

Now you should be able to do forward search (source to output) by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>, and backward search by double-clicking in SumatraPDF.

Hope this helps someone! It is a bit tedious to set it up but it's incredibly useful once it works.

Comment: great answer, but one problem: The ForwardSearch does not work. I got a window: Der Command cannot be executed.

Comment: @Ralf I did not get that feature to work. I advise installing TexStudio http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/. TexStudio is a newer version of TexMakerX (TexMakerX is part of the latest Windows MikTex package I looked at).