# How to have TeXnicCenter reopen PDF window at same monitor location?

Tags: texniccenter, acrobat

I use TeXnixCenter as LaTeX editor. To view the resulting PDF, I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> (build+view), which closes the Acrobat windows with the previous PDF version (if it was open) and then opens the new version of the PDF in an Acrobat window.

The problem is, after build+view, the Acrobat PDF window is *always* positioned in the top-left window of my screen. Putting the window in a more convenient location for me (e.g., on my second monitor) is not remembered; I have to drag it there each time again.

How can I have TeXnicCenter/Acrobat have Acrobat remember the last window position?

*(Note: just for clarity, I am not interested in having the PDF open at a specific/same page, which is the topic of the question: [How to get TeXnicCenter to remember the last page viewed in output PDF (as done automatically by TeXworks)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40902/how-to-get-texniccenter-to-remember-the-last-page-viewed-in-output-pdf-as-done).)*

**Edit**: For readers looking for a solution to this problem, my *workaround* was to install SumatraPDF (and fix TeXnicCenter to interact correctly with it). It works very nice (despite the SumatraPDF website looking so un-cool.)

Comment: I also had this issue and switched to SumatraPDF. I still use Acroread for reading, opening in web browser etc. but for compiling TeX docs I use Sumatra PDF and it stays where it is because it doesn't need to be closed during compilation. I can recommend TeXnicCenter 2 Alpha 3 (not 4) to identify and work with Sumatra.

Comment: @Rabarberski Your question seems to have very little to do with (La)TeX, as where a window opens is dependent on the program in question. You may get more joy asking on SuperUser, for example "How do I get Acrobat to remember it's location on screen?".

Comment: @Jospeh: I thought that TeXnicCenter would be used mainly by LaTeX users, and that these users might hang out primarily on tex.sx, and thus inferred that my problem might have the highest chance of getting useful remarks/solution by posting it here. I agree that the superuser question you suggest would fit well on superuser, but maybe the problem can be solved through TexnicCenter as well? And maybe other tex users suffer the same problem, making it interesting for them as well?

Comment: @percusse: thanks for the useful suggestion. I will have a look at SumatraPDF (BTW: I am already using Alpha 4)

Comment: There's a [TeXnicCenter support forum](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=22) on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/), which has been founded by the original developer of TeXnicCenter. He and other developers read on this site, so you could also post TXC specific problems there.

Comment: @percusse: I installed SumatraPDF, and indeed, after some twiddling to have it interact correctly with TeXnicCenter, it works great! Just wanted to let you (and other readers) know, now they decided to close this question