# Interactive LaTeX code editing, while reading your output? (or jumpind to exact(!) part of the code)

Tags: environments

While writing something in LaTeX, I am usually using RStudio or TeXnicCenter (in past also WinShell), but one of the most tedious things for me is when I am proofreading my work.

For every small mistake or typo that I see, I have to Alt+Tab back to the editor, search for it and fix it.

If I am using TeXnicCenter, then after building .pdf file, the document is focused on the fragment that corresponds lines in code, from which it was being built. This is very convenient, as if I will find a typo few lines below the previous one, then I am finding it almost immediately - I just go down few lines in code.

---

Nevertheless, it would be extremely convenient, if you could have more interactive output preview, which after clicking on it, would take you to the exact code fragment, from which it was generated.

I know that making changes could often require the whole file being generated again, so the output preview could remain unaffected by your changes, but maybe there is something that allows you to do so?

So, what I am looking for is either more dynamic editing or immediately jumping to the code, from which the chosen .pdf part was generated.

I noticed that for some of my beamer .pdf files (which I made by myself), if I double click at any point in document, it opens the file in Notepad++ (maybe because of files association?) and takes me to the end of the frame, within which I clicked. I don't even know, if Notepad++ can be used for compiling .pdf files, and even if, it works for me only for beamer files, but this inspired me to ask this question.

Is there some LaTeX editor or environment, that makes editing big files (like some books or long paper works) easier and allows you to fix small typos and mistakes quickly?

---

P.S.
I keep getting stackexchange pop-up, saying that

> The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be
>   closed

but I have no idea why. The question looks fine for me, however, if there is something against the rules or Meta, then feel free to write about this in comments, and I will try to fix this quickly.

Comment: You are probably looking for something like [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/). It provides [synctex](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/158-synctex-is-here-scroll-click-and-hey-presto#.Wmj_bq6nGCg).

Comment: Overleaf or not, synctex is the critical part. Related: [How to get TeXnicCenter to remember the last page viewed in output PDF (as done automatically by TeXworks)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40902/how-to-get-texniccenter-to-remember-the-last-page-viewed-in-output-pdf-as-done) (where the answers show how to set up TeXnicCenter and Sumatra PDF with synctex support).

Comment: You just need a PDF viewer and an editor which are `synctex` aware. Then you just give the option to the compiler (in your editor or on the command line or using `arara` or whatever) and you can click in the PDF to go to the relevant point in the document. (Ish - more-or-less the right line, usually, depending on how things have changed since you last compiled.) The PDF viewer gets the relevant line number from the synced data and passes it to your editor, which opens the file at the relevant point (or switches to that point, if open). Pretty straightforward, though TeXShop on OS X is better.