# TexnicCenter - view output

Tags: editors, viewers

I want to view the PDF output from TeXnicCenter with Sumatra instead of Adobe Acrobat. How can I change the configuration of TeXnicCenter accordingly?

Comment: In addition, here is the official help: http://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/configuration.html

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12500